# Django: AttributeError - Object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

This view is throwing the AttributeError saying :'PhotoForm' object has no attribute 'reservation'. What happens- the function passes, but doesn't actually upload the image. In debugging it, **the form is not valid.**

I tried printing

- form.reservation
- form.message
- form.photo

But that shows this traceback ( which is the reason why the form isn't valid & not completing the function.

As I built this off other functions that are working, I'm a bit confused. Thanks for the help!

**The HTML Form**

```
<form action="/photo/new/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <dl>
        <dt>{{ form.reservation.label }}</dt>
            <dd><select name="reservation"> {% for reservation in reservations %} <option value="{{reservation.id}}">{{reservation.date}} {{reservation.chef.cook.get_profile.firstname}} - {{reservation.guest.get_profile.firstname}}</option>{% endfor %}</select></dd>
        <dt>{{ form.photo.label }}</dt>
            <dd>{{ form.photo }}</dd>
        <dt> {{ form.message.label }}</dt>
            <dd>{{ form.message }}</dd>
    </dl>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**The View**

```
@login_required
def new_photo(request, template_name="photo/newphoto.html"):

  meals = Reservation.objects.filter(guest=request.user.id)
  form = PhotoForm(request.POST)
  form.data = { "reservations": meals }
  if request.method == 'POST':
    form.photographer = request.user
    form.data.get('reservation')
    print form.reservation
    print form.message
    print form.photo
    if form.is_valid():
      print" hellos"
      save_reservation_photo(request.FILES["photo"])
      photo = form.save(commit=False)
      photo.photographer = request.user
      photo.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/photo/%d/' % photo.id )
  else:
    form = PhotoForm()

  data = {'form':form,'reservations':meals,
    'add':True
  }

  return render_to_response(template_name,
                            data,
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**The Form:**

```
class PhotoForm(forms.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Photo
    fields = ('reservation','photo','message')

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      super(PhotoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**The Model:**

```
class Photo(models.Model):

  photographer = models.ForeignKey(User)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,auto_now_add=True,db_index=True)
  reservation = models.ForeignKey(Reservation)

  message = models.CharField(default='',max_length=140)

  photo = models.ImageField(default='',upload_to="reservation_images/")
```

**The traceback**

```
Traceback:
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/new/
Django Version: 1.2.3
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'lib.debug_toolbar',
 'src',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'lib.debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:

Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/photo/new/
Django Version: 1.2.3
Python Version: 2.7.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'lib.debug_toolbar',
 'src',
 'django.contrib.admin']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'lib.debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  100.                     response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  25.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/emilepetrone/Sites/meal/../meal/src/views.py" in new_photo
  532.     print form.reservation

Exception Type: AttributeError at /photo/new/
Exception Value: 'PhotoForm' object has no attribute 'reservation'
```

Comment: can you post traceback? btw: you dont need to set PhotoForm __init__ because if PhotoForm dont set any constructor then base class constructor will be called

Comment: Did you do a syncdb after adding in the reservation column (or was it in there from the get-go)?

Comment: The exception is coming from a line with `print form.reservation`, which isn't in the code you've posted. Please post the actual code showing the problem.

Comment: I updated the view/call back to show the print statements. Without those, the form is not valid and passes to the "else: form= PhotoForm()" . So the question is why isn't the form valid ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key was having files=request.FILES in the form.

```
@login_required
def new_photo(request, template_name="photo/newphoto.html"):

  form = PhotoForm( user= request.user, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

  if request.method == 'POST':
    form.photographer = request.user
    if form.is_valid():
      photo = form.save(commit=False)
      photo.photographer = request.user
      photo.save()
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/photo/%d/' % photo.id )
```

Comment: although its an old post, but your way of solving the problem is a bit odd. When you are doing `form = PhotoForm(...)` you are already using `request.POST` in that and then again you are checking that `request.method='POST'`

Answer (score 5):

should not forms (with image or file fields) [be initialized with request.FILES](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/)?

```
form = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, but tried it and it didn't solve the problem :/

Answer (score 0):

Your inbound form processing looks a bit odd to me, but I usually don't use ModelForm.  Here's what mine generally look like:

```
def some_form_view(request): 
  if request.method != 'POST': 
    raise Http404  # or whatever 
  form_data = FormClass(request.POST, request.FILES)
  if not form_data.is_valid():
    context['form'] = form_data 
    return render_to_response(...)  # invalid for m

  new_object = ModelObject(
      field=form_data.cleaned_data['field'], 
      other_field=form_data.cleaned_data['other_field'])
  new_object.save()

  context['new_object'] = new_object
  return render_to_response(...)  # success
```

So things to note:

- I don't think "form.reservation" is a valid identifier.  You should just say "print form" or "print str(form)" and not try to print the individual fields.
- You should almost certainly be calling is_valid() before doing anything with that data.  That should/will raise the form validation errors if the form itself is invalid.
- Only ever access the form data directly through form.cleaned_data['foo'] and never via .data, because you're accessing something potentially dangerous coming in from the user.

Hope this helps.