# Attribute Error When UserProfile Object is Added

Tags: mysql, django

I recently migrated  Django 1.7.1 to Django 1.9.1 . If I try to add a UserProfile to a new user (mapped one to one), I get an attribute error.

```
AttributeError at /admin/coffee/userprofile/add/
'bool' object has no attribute '_committed'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/coffee/userprofile/add/
Django Version: 1.9.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'bool' object has no attribute '_committed'
Exception Location: /tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py in pre_save, line 309
Python Executable:  /tmp/idly/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.10
Python Path:    
['/Users/nlokesh/idly',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python27.zip',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/tmp/idly/Extras/lib/python',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/tmp/idly/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-7.1.0-py2.7.egg',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC']
```

Relationship between User and UserProfile in `models.py`:

```
user= models.OneToOneField(User, null=True)
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4777482/django-attributeerror-object-has-no-attribute

Comment: Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10150301/model-has-no-attribute-committed . Could we see the `UserProfile` model?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/17BHGMR